# Issue deleting mails from server

Tags: email, email-client

I have a backup email address on my Mac Os X Server that catches all emails sent to my company. There are now over 100.000 emails in the mailbox. I would like to delete all emails but the mail application crashes because it's too much.

I found the mail on the server in the finder and deleted them there, but I still see the mails in my mail application. They are shown as a little transparent. I tried deleting them from the mail application as well, but they reappear every time. It's driving me crazy!

How can I delete all emails permanently so they don't reappear?

Comment: Use Google Mail and have it check this catch all address, have it download the emails off the server, thus removing it from the server.  It will take a couple days.  Create a filter that places all email in the Trash.

Comment: Can you give some more details. I'm using the mail application on a physical server and the mail account is a pop3 account from my web hosting. Your Google Mail solution seems a bit devious, no?

Comment: You simply should configure Google to check the pop3 account.  This process is documented on Google's website.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, can you send me the link to this documentation? I'm not sure what to look for. Thanks!

Comment: You want to configure Google Mail to check a POP3 email account.  I don't have the documentation handy.  If you need help dealing with Google Mail or any of the browser based email services [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) would be the best place for that question